# Computer crashes while gaming, even after upgrade, not in synthetic tests

Tags: power-supply, crash

Before I upgraded the screens would turn off, sometimes sound still working but more often than not just making that.. sound loop noise of the last sound it was playing.

After the upgrade the PC just reboots, but it turns off completely, fans and everything, not like a soft reboot.

Specs Before Upgrade:

- CPU: AMD FX-8320
- Ram: HyperX 2x8GB DDR3 1866MHz
- Motherboard: Asus M5A97 LE R2.0
- PSU: Seasonic S12II 520W

Upgraded:

- CPU: Intel i7-8700K
- Ram: (forgot the brand) 2x8GB DDR4 2133MHz
- Motherboard: ASUS PRIME Z370-P

everything else stayed the same

I only play Guild Wars 2 and Arma 3, and this mostly happens in Guild Wars 2. I also stream on twitch while gaming, but that doesn't seem to affect the crashes. It even seems to crash more while not streaming.

I did some synthetic tests, CPU only, GPU only and both. After 2 hours on full load, it still didn't crash.

My guess is the PSU, but until I find a way to make it crash on purpose, sending it to service is useless. It's still under warranty, but the shop will ask me to pay shipping costs if they can't find anything wrong with it.

I entered my specs on Seasonic's website, and my consumption is within the PSU's limits. 378W consumption, they recommend a PSU of at least 428W.

I used to have a UPS reated at 600W, I thought that might be the issue. The batteries were dead but I was keeping it for protection. I eliminated that too, and the problem persists.

If you have any tips on how I can diagnose this problem further, I'd really appreciate them, thank you.

Comment: If the system just shuts off without any stop events logged, then it probably is the PSU. You mention synthetic tests but don't mention which ones: I had what sounds like the same problem that I could not reliably reproduce on demand (some games made it happen more often), and then I tried Furmark which forced a shutdown instantly every time. Rather than checking specs, see if you can borrow a known-good psu for an hour. This way you can eliminate the PSU as the source of the problem

Comment: I used Prime95, Furmark and OCCT. And I forgot to mention, nothing is logged, just an unexpected shutdown with bugcheck code 0. The problem with getting another PSU is that this happens rarely, 2-3 times per month. Only once I had it happen twice in the same day.

Comment: Furmark is a great resource